# Is my Socket Server Loop Class correct?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I am getting errors in my server when the client's message type is "connect", it is very strange.

Server Receiver Code:

```
package threads;

public class ReceiveFromClientThread extends Thread {

ObjectInputStream inFromClient = null;
ServerSocket servs = new ServerSocket();
Socket link = null;
Message m = null;

public void run() {

    try {
        this.servs.servs.accept();
        this.inFromClient = new ObjectInputStream(link.getInputStream());
    } catch (SocketException e3) {
        System.err.println(" Connection reset by peer.");
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    while(true) {   
        try {
            if (link.isConnected()) {
                this.m = (Message) inFromClient.readObject(); //SHOULDN'T THIS THREAD PAUSE HERE?

                if (m.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("normal")) {
                      System.out.println("[" + m.getTimestamp() + "] "  
                          + m.getOwner() + " -> " + m.getText());
                      ServerMain.mc.pushMessageToList(this.m); //Added to message list.
                } else if (m.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("connect")) {
                      System.out.println(m.getOwner() + " connected from "
                          + this.link.getInetAddress()+":"+this.link.getPort());
                } else if (m.getType() == "disconnect") {
                      System.err.println("[" + m.getTimestamp() + "] " 
                          + "[Origin: " + m.getIp() + "] " + m.getOwner() 
                          + " Disconnected." );
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        }
    }
}

public ReceiveFromClientThread(Socket link) {
    this.link = link;   
}
}
```

Client Connection Code:

```
ClientMain.sock     = new Socket("127.0.0.1",21215);
ClientMain.oos      = new ObjectOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());

Message m = new Message();
        m = m.setType("connect");
        m.setOwner("Raphael");
        m.setIp(sock.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());
        m.setPcname(sock.getInetAddress().getCanonicalHostName());
        clientmain.ClientMain.oos.writeObject(m);
```

It should be working, but it gives an infinite loop or sometimes a NullPointerException. Is there any error in my code? Shouldn't the server thread suspend on the readObject() line?

Comment: could you please provide the full code of your Client?

Comment: Closes your client the socket after sending the message?

Comment: Yes, does StackOverFlow provide somewhere I can share the code?

Comment: here they are, I was learning how to correctly use github, the codes are on the following repositories:

https://github.com/raphaelbgr/SocketServer
https://github.com/raphaelbgr/SwingSocketClient

Answer (score 2):

From the bit of code you submitted, the client looks fine but the server has a few issues.

When you create a server socket, you must specify a port to bind to (in the constructor). This define on which port you listen and wait for clients.

Once you have a bound socket listening, you call `.accept()` to accept clients incoming connections. the `.accept()` method will return a socket that represent the connected client. Usually you will loop on `.accept()` and spawn a thread each time it returns to handle the new client (you may have multiple clients). To communicate with the client, you need to use the returned socket.

In your code, you seem to be using an unbound server socket, and your `link` client socket is definitely not coming from `.accept()`.

Edit: As Joachim pointed out, you also need to handle the case where the socket is closed, by breaking the loop, for example.

Comment: I tried do adapt the code from the original one, wich is much more complicated to write here, does StackOverFlow provide somewhere to put the full code?

Comment: @raphaelbgr no, to do that you need to paste your code on another website and put a link

Answer (score 0):

It's completely wrong. This kind of code can only correctly handle one client at a time.

- One way or anothe, the result of calling `accept()` must be a new `Runnable` that is executed in its own thread, and whose `run()` method constructs all its own streams and calls methods that do all the I/O on the accepted socket.
- None of that must happen in that `Runnable`'s constructor, which is still part of the accept loop's thread.
- The accepted socket and those streams must be instance members *of that `Runnable`,* not of the server class. The loop more usually looks something like this:

  ```
  while (true)
  {
      new Thread(new ConnectionHandler(ss.accept())).start();
  }
  ```

  where `ConnectionHandler` implements `Runnable` as described above.
- Note that the loop doesn't do anything else, and specifically that it doesn't alter any instance state in the class it is part of.